# scraping data from web page within <div> tag with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape product name and the rating from a webpage. Upon inspecting the element, I know I need to get the data from **product__title** and **attraqt-star-rating-stars__bar**. But I am not sure how to do it as this is embedded within the multiple layers of  tag. I've tried the following with no avail; any suggestions are welcome.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url = 'https://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/shop-online/159/oral-hygiene-and-dental-care'
stores <- read_html(url) 

stores %>% html_nodes('body') %>% 
  html_nodes('.product__title') %>% 
  rvest::html_text()

stores %>% html_nodes('body') %>% 
  html_nodes('attraqt-star-rating-stars__bar') %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Data is pulled dynamically from an API call. As the json returned is nested you need to extract the desired info e.g., by writing a couple of user-defined functions.

I first extract the listings (list of products), then have a function `get_info`, which takes an individual product listing and extracts the title and rating and returns a `tibble`. As the index at which the rating may appear can vary, I have an additional helper function `get_rating_index`, which retrieves dynamically the correct index for the rating. This function passes the index back to `get_info`.

I apply `get_info` over the list of product info, `listings`, using `map_dfr` to generate a final `DataFrame` from each `tibble`.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data <- jsonlite::read_json("https://www.chemistwarehouse.com.au/searchapi/webapi/search/category?category=159&index=0&sort=")

listings <- data$universes$universe[[1]]$`items-section`$items$item

get_info <- function(listing) {
  tibble(
    title = listing$attribute[[2]]$value[[1]]$value,
    rating = listing$attribute[[get_rating_index(listing$attribute)]]$value[[1]]$value %>% as.numeric()
    ) -> t
  return(t)
}

get_rating_index <-function(attribute){
  return(match(T, map(attribute, ~{.x$name == 'bv_star_rating'})))
}

dental_product_ratings <- purrr::map_dfr(listings, get_info)
```

Comment: Hi, any idea why we can't just extract the node div.product__title?

Comment: Because the data you see on the website is loaded dynamically via JavaScript which runs in the browser to update the page. When you use rvest these additional requests do not happen so that content is missing.